# JS Array Sorting Using Expression

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to bring the related object to the first index of the array using `sort` function?

Here is what I tried using `sort` only

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 'a',
    name: 'test name 1'
  },
  {
    id: 'b',
    name: 'test name 2'
  },
  {
    id: 'c',
    name: 'test name 3'
  }
];

const testId = 'c';


const sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => a.id === testId || b.id === testId ? 1 : -1);

console.log(sortedArr); // logs b, a, c but the expected result is c, a, b
```

Comment: It seems to work because if we replace `1 : -1` to `-1 : 1` the part with "c" is not the last but the first

Comment: Also, I suggest you to test on only one, because it will be too many times 1 instead of `-1`, let me make an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is because everytime that `a` OR `b` are the `testId`, it will be "bumped". So, if you check only to one value it works.

Here an example :

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 'c'
  },
  {
    id: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 'b'
  }
];

function checkFor(myList, testId) {
    console.log('Checking for ' + testId);
    const sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => b.id === testId ? 1 : -1);

    console.log(sortedArr);
}

checkFor(arr, 'c');
checkFor(arr, 'b');
```